# Email Sending Task in Windows Phone Universal App

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I was trying to write an Email sending code for Windows Phone Universal App. This is the Code that I have written in my Event Handler:

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailMessage email = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailMessage();
email.Subject = "Good morning";
email.Body = "Hello, how are you?";

var emailRecipient = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailRecipient(email.Address);

email.To.Add(emailRecipient);

await Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailManager.ShowComposeNewEmailAsync(email);
```

This code works for my Windows Phone 8.1 App. But it's not working in the Universal App. Shall I have to add any reference? Is there any way to make it work in the Universal app?

Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: So what's the error about? refrence or method?

Comment: The method is asynchronous method. But the problem is I get error in Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailMessage. When I declare:

var emailMessage = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailMessage();

I get an error. There is a red line below the Email in Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailMessage line.

The error says - "The type or namespace name 'Email' does not exist in the namespace 'Windows.ApplicationModel' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

Comment: please read my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Windows Store App, Windows.ApplicationModel.Email namespace is not supported.

See [EmailMessage class in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.applicationmodel.email.aspx).

You can send mail use **mailto** protocol, and use **LaunchUriAsync** method. like this:

```
await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(
    new Uri(
        "mailto:someemail@somedomain.com?subject=SomeSubject&body=mail content"
        ));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man. :) You are such a live saver. Respect to you. @Chris Shao

Comment: mailto protocol doesn't support attachment though

Comment: I don't see anything on that page that suggests this doesn't work for 8.x store apps. The documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.email.emailmanager.showcomposenewemailasync.aspx states 8.x or 8.x phone required for emailmanager in the same Windows.ApplicationModel.Email namespace.

Answer (score 1):

In UWP development, a lot of codes still same with Windows Phone 8.1 /Windows Store App. As below shown send an email with attachment.

```
EmailMessage email = new EmailMessage();
email.To.Add(new EmailRecipient("test@developerpublish.com"));
email.Subject = "Blog pos`enter code here`t by @isenthil";
var file = await GetTextFile();
email.Attachments.Add(new EmailAttachment(file.Name, file));
await EmailManager.ShowComposeNewEmailAsync(email);
```

Comment: This doesn't work as **Windows.ApplicationModel.Email** namespace is not supported.

Comment: This is the only reasonable answering *style* I found among almost all your answers, though it may not solve the OP problem, it is still at least OK. If only you could answer like this for all other answers.

Comment: Thank you. I will improve more.